# CSS browser support for min() and max() in 2018?

Tags: css

I'm looking to use `min()` and `max()` in my project and I'm wondering what the browser support is in 2018? Just wondering if I need to bother using the `@supports` at-rule.

So I could write:

```
.px-4-safe {
    padding-left: max(1rem, env(safe-area-inset-left));
    padding-right: max(1rem, env(safe-area-inset-right));
}
```

Instead of:

```
.px-4-safe {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

@supports (padding: max(0px)) {
  .px-4-safe {
    padding-left: max(1rem, env(safe-area-inset-left));
    padding-right: max(1rem, env(safe-area-inset-right));
  }
}
```

Comment: Watch this space… https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min#Browser_compatibility

Comment: ^ Watch this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max#Browser_compatibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min#Browser_compatibility

and CanIUse

https://caniuse.com/#search=min()\

https://caniuse.com/#search=max()\

There is no compatibility info, which suggests you are out of luck at this stage.